YouTube Playlist when embedded is replaced with 1st video in playlist and no playlist logo
I am trying to embed a YT playlist and when the code runs for 0.5 seconds the playlist embed template/thumbnail is shown and the replaced by first video of the playlist, and when open with option "Watch on YouTube" there is no playlist on right hand side(video suggestion panel) to show that this video is part of a playlist. Please help if this makes sense.
Playlist embed Template/thumbnail means:
The YT thumbnail should show the video is part of a Playlist
but in my case it is showing like:
No sign that the video is part of a playlist
Code i am using:
  <iframe
  width="560"
  height="400"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/playlist?list=PL590L5WQmH8cSyqzo1PwQVUrZYgLcGZcG"
  
  frameborder="0"
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
  allowfullscreen
  referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
  title="YouTube Playlist"
></iframe>

Code Description: used "videoseries" and "playlist" tried bith but same result (no playlist logo on Top Right Corner).
Wanted to know, is this fault of from YouTube/Google updates in policy? I read few but can't locate exact where its been discontinued. Or my PC is at fault for some cache relate bug.
I implemented the same code in React + vanilla HTML project = same result/ same bug.
Thanks for looking into it.
